# How to detect when finger slides off of touch display in Corona

Tags: events, touch, coronasdk

For the Corona sdk, how do you detect when the finger slides off of the display? The sample code "dragme" provided by Corona run on the simulator allows your finger (pointer) to drag off of the screen and on again and continues to monitor the position of the finger so I cant learning anything from that.

Answer (score 0):

Can we do like this?
use a runtime listener to check for "moved" touch events going over the boundary using display.viewableContentWidth/Height?

```
local xMin = (display.viewableWidth-display.viewableContentWidth)/2
local xMax = xMin+display.viewableContentWidth
local yMin = (display.viewableHeight-display.viewableContentHeight)/2
local yMax = yMin+display.viewableContentHeight
Runtime:addEventListener("touch",function()
  if event.phase == "moved" then
    if event.x < xMin or event.x > xMax or 
         event.y < yMin or event.y > yMax then

         --do something
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi cctan. I considered this. But what if you slide your finger off the side of the screen quickly so that the last on-screen move event falls within the viewableContentWidth? Then this slide-off-screen-detection approach will not work. Furthermore, limiting the touchable real-estate is not attractive.     However, someone did suggest that sliding finger off screen does produce an "ended" phase on a device (which I cant test yet). I just wish Ansca would document this.